# Dom4j -> Invalid XPath expression

Tags: xml, parsing, xpath, nodes, dom4j

I have a .txt file in the form of xml.
input.txt looks like below which has bin/envelope/document

I referred https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java_xml/java_dom4j_parse_document.htm but getting an error
org.dom4j.InvalidXPathException: Invalid XPath expression: '/bin/envelope/document'. Caused by: org.jaxen.dom4j.DocumentNavigator.getInstance()Lorg/jaxen/Navigator;

Below code is in main() inside try - catch block but last line throws error

```
    File inputFile = new File("input.txt");
    SAXReader reader = new SAXReader();
    Document document = reader.read(inputFile);
    List<Node> nodes = document.getRootElement().selectNodes("/bin/envelope/document" );
```

I am using dom4j-1.3.jar and jaxen-1.1.3.jar

Appreciate your help!Thank You.

Comment: Please edit your post and add the XML you are trying to process.

Comment: What about removing `.getRootElement()` in your last line of code ? `List<Node> nodes = document.selectNodes("/bin/envelope/document");`

Comment: I did remove getRootElement() as recommended but still get error. Below is the xml format <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><bin name="default" spoolid="35280614" inputfile="CC"><envelope startpagenumber="1"><document batchid="31586933" ....Basically, i get problem when i run the example from https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java_xml/java_dom4j_parse_document.htm as well, not sure if you can successfully run that example? I get a warning message 'Type safety: List need unchecked conversion  to conform to List<Node>' at line List<Node> nodes = document.selectNodes("bin/envelope/document");